# Using MAX7301 GPIO Expander for Raspberry Pi Switching and Chip Selecting

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, raspberry-pi, expander

I'm designing a PCB that uses Analog Devices' MAX7301AAX GPIO Expander IC to expand the Raspberry PI's GPIOs.

[Digikey MAX7301](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc-maxim-integrated/MAX7301AAX-T/1514611?utm_adgroup=General&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax%20Shopping_Product_Zombie%20SKUs&utm_term=&utm_content=General&gclid=CjwKCAjw3dCnBhBCEiwAVvLcuxaS_HK-lQp_RHssqPMwtMsYK_9jD9dPCl7G4dbs_8D0QDE1cQagkRoC3M8QAvD_BwE)

The reason I'm using this IC is that my application requires a lot of output pins for SPI's CHIP SELECT and digital switches to output HIGH/LOW.

For example: P4 to P14, each pin is a Chip Select to enable an device through SPI; and P15 to P25, each pin is able to output HIGH(>2V) or LOW(<0.8V) to control digital switches ON/OFF.
[image: fig-2]

I have a few concerns that can't find answers from the datasheet:

1. Can these GPIOs pins(p4-p31) have multiple pins outputing HIGH(V>2.0V) at the same time to turn on multiple switches at the same time? ex. p5,p7,p9,p11 output **HIGH at the same time**.
2. Will input a new command reset the previous command? ex. **first set p5,p7,p9,p11 as HIGH**, will a **new command for p28 reset** previous pins' status?
   In other words, does each pin act as an independent GPIO and does not intefer with other pin's commands?

Thank you for your answers!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet says:

> The MAX7301 ... provides microprocessors with up to 28 ports.
> Each port is individually user configurable to either a logic input
> or logic output. Each port can be configured either as a push-pull logic
> output capable of sinking 10mA and sourcing 4.5mA, or a Schmitt logic input
> with optional internal pullup.

It does not mention any additional restrictions, except for the total sink current.